# How to show the current value of slide on the label in a dynamic tableview cell when the slide is dragging?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I created a dynamic tableview cell with a slider and a label inside.
I'm trying to show the current value of slider on the label, but I don't want to do it by reloading the table.
The following is my code:

```
class SlideControl:UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var slide_1:UISlide!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_1:UILabel!
}

cell.slide_1.addTarget(nil,action:#selector(valueChanging(sender:)),for:.ValueChanged);

@objc func valueChanging(sender:UISlide){
    //???
}
```

I tried to achieve this function by using addTarget, but I don't know how to do except reload the tableview.
Is there any other good way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please show some code for people to understand what you have done so far.

Comment: What is a `UISlide`? Since you probably mean `UISlider`, you should update your question with real code. Copy and paste actual, relevant code into your question. It's hard to help when you post fake, invalid code.

Comment: Thanks fpr your comment.I won't make the same mistake next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the target in the `SlideControl` class and change label text in the `valueChanging` method

```
class SlideControl:UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var slide_1:UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_1:UILabel!
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        slide_1.addTarget(nil,action:#selector(valueChanging(sender:)),for:.valueChanged)
    }
    @objc func valueChanging(sender:UISlider){
        label_1.text = "\(sender.value)"
    }
}
```